A question about formal prepositions
Which is more formal: "the song is streamed by the artist" or "the song is streamed from the artist?"

"The song is streamed from the artist" is odd; I would expect a song to be streamed from a venue (a place).

What do you mean? Are you talking about a live broadcast from singer to listener, a singer uploading a song to a streaming site, or someone playing a song from a streaming site? Or do you mean that the song is available for streaming?

Songs are streamed by services from servers.

If the artist made the stream and performed in it, presumably a live stream, then it's by the artist, but from a venue/place. This has nothing to do with formality or informality. Books, songs, symphonies, artworks, paintings, performances, etc, are generally by someone. Not "from" someone.

@BillyKerr You just wouldn't say the artist made the stream. The artist composes the song, it is performed and the performance is streamed...

@Lambie Sorry, I fail to see an issue here.  To say that something was "streamed by someone" seems perfectly fine to me. I'm not your down voter BTW.

All I'm saying is that the OP's formulation is not usual. Also, songs aren't streamed "from a place" but from a service, like Spotify,

There's nothing inherently formal or informal about prepositions - context dictates which you should use and in most contexts, the preposition choice is right or wrong rather than formal or informal. I feel that both of these are wrong, not for grammatical reasons, but for technical reasons in the context.
Broadly speaking, "by" indicates the agent of an action, ie who is doing or causing something, or the method used; "from" indicates the source of something.
"Streaming" refers to the transmission of data, so I would say music is streamed "from" the internet, a website, a server, or the name of a service, for example "the song can be streamed from Spotify". The artist is not personally doing the transmission of data, so it seems technically wrong to say it is streamed 'from' them. As "by" can indicate means or method, you could say, for example, "you can hear the song by streaming it from Spotify".

In many fewer words, I said the same thing.

@lambie I never read comments.

It's not a comment. It's an answer.

@lambie I can't see an answer - is it invisible because so many people downvoted it?

Not at all. It's there.

@lambie Oh yes, its winking in and out of existence though. I see you posted it 3 days after mine. So when you said "In many fewer words, I said the same thing" you meant "I paraphrased your work and expect the same praise for it"

No, I didn't read yours. I never copy people's answers.

@Lambie If you never read it, how do you know yours said the same?

Because I read it post facto to writing my answer.

There is no such thing as a formal preposition. Prepositions are just prepositions.
Songs by singers or bands are streamed by services from servers.
That's the least complicated way to express this.
The songs are [sung or recorded] by singers, not the streaming.

Disregard the downvoters. :)
